# Fire event handler when close modal outside of bootstrap model area

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and angularjs in my project.
I use Bootstrap ['Modals'](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp). I'm trying to customize some of the default features.

How do I fire event handler in controller when I close the modal window by clicking on the background not the close button.

Comment: What have you done yet??

Answer (score 2):

The `hidden.bs.modal` event fires whenever the modal is closed, no matter how you close it. See the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

**EDIT**

In the code snippet you showed me, the event was firing, but you were using `$interval` instead of `setInterval`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#closeModal").click(function () {
            $("#modalWindow").modal("hide");
        });
        $("#modalWindow").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
            console.log("I fired");
            var t = "333";
            self.timer = setInterval(function () {
                checkUpdate();
            }, self.delay, false);
        });
    });
```

Whenever I'm having problems with events, I always put a console.log at the top of the callback function to make sure it is definitely being fired. 9/10 times it is and its the code in the callback that is crashing.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#closeModal").click(function () {
                $("#modalWindow").modal("hide");
            });
            $("#modalWindow").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                var t = "333";
                self.timer = $interval(function () { checkUpdate(); }, self.delay, false);
            });
        })

Comment: Any idea why it not fired?